# Z-score across a whole matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, multidimensional-array, normalization

How would I calculate the z-score of an entire 3 dimensional matrix in Matlab?

The Matlab command `zscore` standardises across vectors in just one of the dimensions of multidimensional arrays.

`zscore` documentation: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/zscore.html

Comment: You can convert the matrix `M` to a vector using `M(:)`. But then again, I don’t know what z-score is, you might want to add a short explanation and/or a link to the MATLAB documentation for the function you’re using.

Comment: Hi Cris, It is a method of normalising the data. I think your method could work if I then transform the vector back into a matrix again at the end after Z-scoring.

Comment: @NeuroPainsme if my answer solved your problem, please consider marking it as accepted using the tick under the voting buttons

Answer (score 3):

Here I show two equivalent methods:

1. You can `edit zscore` to view how the function works, or the documentation linked in your question gives the equation for `zscore`:

   [image: zscore]

   We can calculate this manually using the `mean` and `std` (standard deviation).

   ```
   M = rand( 3, 5 ) * 10
   >> M =
      9.5929       1.4929       2.5428       9.2926       2.5108
      5.4722       2.5751       8.1428       3.4998       6.1604
      1.3862       8.4072       2.4352        1.966       4.7329

   Z = ( M - mean(M(:)) ) / std(M(:)) % using M(:) to operate on the array as a vector
   >> Z =
      1.6598      -1.0771     -0.72235       1.5583     -0.73316
     0.26743     -0.71145       1.1698     -0.39899          0.5
     -1.1131       1.2591      -0.7587     -0.91727     0.017644
   ```

   The advantage of this method is that you don't have to use the statistics toolbox required by `zscore`. This minor disadvantage is you lose the input checking of `zscore`, and protections if the standard deviation is 0.
2. If you want to use `zscore` then you can use `reshape`, after calculating the `zscore` as if it were a vector:

   ```
   Z = reshape( zscore(M(:)), size(M) )
   >> Z =
      1.6598      -1.0771     -0.72235       1.5583     -0.73316    
     0.26743     -0.71145       1.1698     -0.39899          0.5
     -1.1131       1.2591      -0.7587     -0.91727     0.017644
   ```

Note that both of these methods should behave the same as the standard `zscore(M)` for a vector input `M`.